# Remove Transitive Dependency for Sonar Fix Vulnerability from React Package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, nexus-iq

My Package File is as follow

```
{
  "name": "trial-ui",
  "version": "5.1.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "jest": {
    "resetMocks": false
  },
  "files": [
    "build",
    "Staticfile"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.6",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.x",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.8.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.38",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.2.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.16",
    "@types/jest": "25.1.3",
    "@types/node": "13.7.7",
    "@types/react": "16.9.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.5",
    "axios": "0.26.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "date-holidays": "1.4.12",
    "execa": "3.4.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.3",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.6.5",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "material-table": "^1.69.3",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-idle-timer": "^5.4.1",
    "react-redux": "7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "5.5.0",
    "redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.4",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "4.4.1",
    "typescript": "5.2.2",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "yup": "1.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie >= 9"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie >= 9"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "12.1.10",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.6",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "enzyme": "3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-config-xo-react": "0.16.0",
    "eslint-config-xo-space": "0.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "5.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.1",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.20.0",
    "husky": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "26.6.0",
    "jest-junit": "^15.0.0",
    "jest-react-hooks-shallow": "^1.5.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "pretty-quick": "2.0.1",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.12.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.8"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting two Sonar Vulnerability

```
static-eval  2.0.2 & ejs:3.1.9 w
```

hich has
Dependency tree as follow:

```
` Aopplicatyion ->react-scripts : 5.0.0 ->bfj : 7.1.0 ->jsonpath : 1.1.1->static-eval : 2.0.2
react-scripts : 5.0.0 ->workbox-webpack-plugin : 6.6.0 ->workbox-build : 6.6.0 ->@surma/rollup-plugin-off-main-thread : 2.2.3 -> ejs : 3.1.9 `
```

I am told to remove the Transitive dependency from Build and check the status
so I want how to remove it from dependency I am using npm and node version 16

Kindly help me I tried Upgrading the packages to it most non-vulnerable state, deleted package, tried to add it in resolution but nothing helped